# Не открывается bat-файл через bat-файл

Tags: cmd, bat, запуск

Имею следующий скрипт bat:

```
call runas /user:ilya_3_b /savecred C:\Users\ilya_3_b\Desktop\selenium\RTS-PIK\dms-selenium-tests\TestSelenium\bin\Debug\TestAll_TC_3_local.bat
pause
```

Он не работает, при запуске просить ввести любой символ для продолжения и закрывается,
НО при запуске через cmd (НЕ ЧЕРЕЗ батник) кодом:

```
runas /user:ilya_3_b /savecred cmd
cd C:\Users\ilya_3_b\Desktop\selenium\RTS-PIK\dms-selenium-tests\TestSelenium\bin\Debug\TestAll_TC_3_local.bat
```

Запуск требуется осуществить под другим пользователем (нужно протестировать параллельное автотестирование)
Все отлично работает и проект запускается, не могу понять в чем дело, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: А `CALL` там зачем?

Comment: Поменять Call на Start?

Comment: Ну не поменять, а убрать CALL и добавить START CMD /C.

Comment: Спасибо, открывает теперь под нужным пользователем, но батник все равно почему то не хочет работать

Comment: `echo 
start cmd c/ 
runas /user:ilya_3_b /savecred C:\Users\ilya_3_b\Desktop\selenium\RTS-PIK\dms-selenium-tests\TestSelenium\bin\Debug\TestAll_TC_3_local.bat
pause`